# java foreach database List value

Tags: java

`data` is selecte all users in database
it will print out:

```
[com.test.abc.user.domain.User@b22379c, com.test.abc.user.domain.User@364b96e5, com.test.abc.user.domain.User@1c9fb03c, com.test.abc.user.domain.User@37eb41d2]
```

I want to know how can I get the value in it .

I want to make it to json string like `str` so that the front end can get it
Please help me !!

```
@ResponseBody
public String getList() {

    List<User> data = memberObj.getCurrentMembers() ;
    System.out.println(data);

    //data to string

    String str = "{\"data\": [{\"id\": \"1\",\"account\": \"a@gmail.com\",\"name\": \"sky\",\"nick\": \"abc\"}]}";

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [google gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library

```
List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
list.add(new User());
list.add(new User());
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `User` class a `toString()` method.

```
class User {

    String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that what the OP is after is some JSON encoding mechanism.

Comment: @npinti - It is difficult to tell isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

When you printout data with

```
System.out.println(data)
```

you just print out the structure, not the objects in it.

Additionaly, you do the same here:

```
String str = "{\"data\": [{\"id\": \"1\",\"account\": \"a@gmail.com\",\"name\": \"sky\",\"nick\": \"abc\"}]}";
```

you just return an object not a value, you have to do this with a for or while loop.

Comment: How to do the loop? I have no idea